# connect matlab and python using pymatbridge

Tags: python, matlab

While I am trying to connect python with matlab using pymatbridge, I am getting the following error..

```
MATLAB started and connected!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pscript.py", line 4, in <module>
    res = mlab.run('/home/GuestAccounts/Intern002/FingerPrint/fingerprintnew.m')
AttributeError: 'Matlab' object has no attribute 'run'
```

how can I rectify this?  I used the following script for the connection

```
from pymatbridge import Matlab
mlab = Matlab(matlab='/pkgs/matlab/R2009a/bin/matlab')
mlab.start()
res = mlab.run('/home/GuestAccounts/Intern002/FingerPrint/fingerprintnew.m')
print res['result']
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://arokem.github.io/python-matlab-bridge/), looks like you should be using:

```
res = mlab.run_func('../file.m')
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer and now it shows  
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: honestly I have not tested this library. I simply quickly glanced over the docs and saw you are using the wrong method :) But I suspect that the returned value wasn't properly encoded in JSON. From what I can tell, this package runs a TCP server on the MATLAB side and use JSON to encode messages

Comment: btw what does the `fingerprintnew.m` function return when you run it in a normal MATLAB session?

Comment: actually that function will read two fingerprint images and extract the minutiae points and save it in a text file.  I did not give anything to return.. what can I give?

Comment: in that case I think you should just call it without expecting any return values: `mlab.run_fun('...')`.. Perhaps you should start by familiarizing yourself with how your code works in MATLAB before calling it from Python